# Ajax handling with Gatling

Tags: gatling

this is regarding a web browser Load test using gatling. i'm having a drop down once i clicked on that it will send an ajax call to db and reeving drop down data from a table.table as below.

```
|dropdown_did|drodown name|
|12089       |Samsung     |
|12090       |Apple       |
```

Drop down html as below.

```
<div id="ext-gen274" class="x-combo-list-inner" style="width: 148px; margin-bottom: 8px; height: 63px;">
<div class="x-combo-list-item">--Select--</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected">Samsung</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item">Apple</div>
</div>
```

when gatling recorder is ran it records drop down selection with "dropdown_did" .for an example formParam("Dropdown" , "12089") .but when re running i need to run example as formParam("Dropdown" , "Samsung") , but it fails.Can any have any idea to solve this issue ? formParam("Dropdown" , "12089") is also fails.

Comment: can any one help to resolve this issue.only the ajax posts are not working .